# How to decode the message sent from NetConnection.call(methodName, responder, parameter) by Java

Tags: java, actionscript, air, blazeds

I am using Java Servlet as my server side. However I don't know how to decode the message sent from the function NetConnection.call of Flash.
I download BlazeDS as my AMF3 decoder. But how can I read "methodName" and parameters from the byteArray.

Answer (score 0):

This probably should have been a comment, as I'm not sure how BlazeDS works. I've used `NetConnection.call()` with Flash Media Server (FMS). However, it might work the same way with any other AMF server:

With FMS, you don't try to read the method name or the parameters from a byte array. Instead, you define a method on the server that so this method has the same name and accepts the same parameters that you are passing when you use `NetConnection.call()`.